# When running python project from source, how to avoid conflict with installed package

Tags: python, ipython, python-import, python-module

I have been using an open source package installed via pip and running inside a Jupyter Notebook IPython environment.

I needed to modify the source of the package so I cloned the repo locally and made the changes and imported the local package instead of the installed package with no problem.

**The problem I have is that inside the project source it imports its own package which is importing the installed package instead of the source project and causes a conflict in the code in a few cases**.

Say the package name is `PackageA`, originally installed via `pip install PackageA`. I now have the source code for `Package A` in `libs/` directory underneath my project directory. `projectDir/libs/PackageA`. I am importing the project via `from libs.PackageA import PackageA as pa`, however in the source code (in almost every file) it has `import PackageA as pa`.

I can go through the source and change every instance of `import PackageA as pa` with `from .. import PackageA as pa` but this occurs in probably over 100 files as some files have multiple import statements and its also very untidy as some files are in sub directories requiring `from .... import PackageA as pa`.

Is there a way to redirect the import to use the local version instead of the installed version (I have already uninstalled the pip installed version).

I am fairly new to python (not to software development) so is there a best practice for this type of setup as I'm sure its fairly common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add `sys.path.append("../libs")` before project start.

Comment: Thank you, this worked with a small modification. The path needs to be `"libs/PackageA"` and it needs to be put at the start of sys.path using `sys.path = ['libs/PackageA'] + sys.path`